# Django: How to perform correlated query from two tables?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have `Demographic` table in `models.py`:

```
class Demographic(models.Model):
    patient_id = models.IntegerField(unique= True ,primary_key=True)
    country_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient_id)
```

Country of birth contains a country for each patient, eg. 'Cyprus' or 'Greece' or 'UK' or 'Romania' or ...

Also I have `Diagnosis` table that contains:

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    diagnosis_option = models.CharField( max_length=150)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Demographic)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient)
```

Diagnosis option contains a diagnosis for each patient e.g. 'Thalassaemia a' or 'thalassaemia b' or 'Sickle' or ...

I want to create a correlated query in `views.py`. I want to get total number of patients by country of birth per diagnosis option.

Eg. Cyprus:

1. Thalassaemia a: 2 patients
2. Thalassaemia b: 2 patients

Romania:

1. Thalassaemia a: 1 patient
2. Sickle: 3 patients

Do you know how to create this query?

Comment: Are instances of the `Demographic` model the same as "patients"?  (If so, why isn't the model called `Patient`?)  Your models only allow for a single `Demographic` per `Diagnosis`, so you can't even represent the data you are looking for, let alone query it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `Demographic` contains the demographics data for each patient so it contains much more fields!

Comment: If demographic table is demographc data for patients, should patient_id be a primary key for that? It should ideally be a foreign key to the patient table. At this stage, it would seem best if you could post your models.

Comment: @e4c5 I don't have a extra patient table. The patient_id is the primary key of `Demographic`.

Comment: My point still stands:  each `Diagnosis` can only refer to a single `Demographic` instance.  Since there is only a single one, you can't group them by country.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes it's one-to-one. But I want to find country and for this country count the number of a certain diagnosis. And do this for all diagnosis and for all countries saved in database.

Comment: If you want to group by diagnosis, you should have the reference the other way around: Link to the diagnosis from the patient.  This way, each patient could have only a single diagnosis, but many patients can link to the same diagnosis.  With that model, it would make sense to group patients for a single diagnosis by country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question, correctly you want the count of each diseases for each country. In that case, the following query ought to do it.

```
from django.db.models import Count

Diagnosis.objects.values(
                         'diagnosis_option','patient__country_of_birth'
                        ).annotate(c = Count('diagnosis_option'))
```

Comment: Great! That's it! Thank you!

Comment: `diagnosis_option` may contain more than one option for example `[u"[u'b-thalassaemia syndromes', u'Sickle cell syndromes']]`. In that case I want to count separately `b-thalassaemia syndromes` and `Sickle cell syndromes` and not as one option. Is this possible?

Comment: That wouldn't be. As we discussed in the other thread. Databases are simply not geared to store comma separated data

Comment: So, what do you propose?

Comment: definitely to normalize the data.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: It's a bit of a lengthy subject and cannot be discussed in comments. My suggestion is to read up on it and then post a question with your models.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below ORM query will give you number of patients per country_of_birth per diagnosis option.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Diagnosis.objects.values('patient__country_of_birth', 'diagnosis_option').annotate(patient_count=Count('id'))
```